# Divide mysql to several set for cross validation

Tags: java, mysql, recommendation-engine, cross-validation

Hi I have created a method to recommend movies from Movielens dataset. The problem with me is how to divide table in the database based on user watched movies into folds to apply cross-validation. This example explains what I'm looking for in details. Assume someone watched 12 movies and I will apply 3-fold cross validation, so I need to have 1 set as test and 3 sets as training where 12/3 = 4 which is number of set. In order to evaluate my recommender method I need to compare test set predictions with the other sets one by one, so I need to retrieve user movie in 4 groups do not contain repetitive movies. Does anyone have any idea how to retrieve data of the following example into sets in mysql database ?

```
ID| User_ID|    Movie_ID|   Movie_Title|    Movie_Genre|    Rating|
107747| 3|  480|    Jurassic Park|  Adventure|  4|
107748| 3|  590|    Dances with Wolves| Drama, Western| 4|
107749| 3|  648|    Mission: Impossible|    Action| 3|
107750| 3|  1198|   Raiders of the Lost Ark|    Adventure|  5|
107751| 3|  1259|   Stand by Me|    Drama|  5|
107752| 3|  1266|   Unforgiven| Western|    5|
107753| 3|  1270|   Back to the Future| Sci-Fi| 3|
107754| 3|  1291|   Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade| Action| 4|
107755| 3|  1378|   Young Guns| Western|    5|
107756| 3|  1379|   Young Guns II|  Western|    4|
107757| 3|  1394|   Raising Arizona|    Comedy| 4|
107758| 3|  1431|   Beverly Hills Ninja|    Comedy| 3|
```

So, I trying to retrieve these 12 movies as 3 groups where each group contains 4 movies where these groups contain unique movies, in other word movie should not be exist in more than group. I'm using Java to retrieve these data from database. Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your method with the MovieLens 100k dataset which has cross-folds already done for you. Check out grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ for the writeup and the data. You can also download LensKit if you want to have a framework do this for you -- then you can just write your recommender algorithm in Java.

Edit:
Based on Michael Ekstrand's excellent collaborative filtering explanation (http://md.ekstrandom.net/research/pubs/cf-survey/cf-survey.pdf), here's the method you can use:

1. Since you want 3-fold cross-validation, you will go through each user in turn and separate her ratings (randomly or otherwise) into 3 parts. We'll call them A, B, and C.
2. Now let's try to solve for A. So concatenate all of the users' B and C ratings into a training set. Train your model on this BC dataset.
3. Collaborative filtering requires a model (which you just built), a user's history of ratings, and some hidden part of that history which we'll try to predict to measure how good our algorithm is. So for each user in turn, you have part A which your model knows nothing about. Separate that part into two: A1 and A2. First, use A1 as the known user history, the input to your method. If you're trying to recommend a Top-N list, make that list and then see how many of those N items actually appear in set A2. If you're trying to predict ratings, then go through set A2 and predict all item ratings, then "uncover" the real ratings and measure your error.
4. Repeat using A2 as your known user history.
5. Repeat, but training on AC and testing on B1 and B2. Then repeat again training on AB and testing on C1 and C2. Remember all of your results and average them together. That's your performance.

Let's go back to point 1. I think it's probably easiest to select all movies from the database for a user and have them in a Java collection. Then you can use Collections.shuffle() to permute the list, if you want to use random order for training rather than time-based order. Take a third of the list at a time, based on its size.

I don't understand your point about having movies only exist in one group. A user can only have one rating for a movie (or at least, you are almost always only concerned with the most recent rating). So partitioning a user's rating list will by default not include duplicates from one partition to another. But when you put all user's Part As together, for example, of course there will be many ratings for popular movies.

Comment: Dear @Runner1928 thank you very much for your reply. I knew that Movielens 100k dataset has cross-fold, but the problem that I'm using  Movielens1m dataset which does not have any cross-fold ready and I have to create my own folds. For your second suggestion which is LensKit, I already built all my work and new techniques over the Movielens, so it is very difficult to transfer every thing to LensKit.  So, do you have any idea how to solve this problem form mysql and split table based on user's watched movies? Many thanks in advance.